# Python: Is there a way to count the frequency of a number in a list by only using a counting variable and appending an empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, statistics

I thought of dividing the code into two parts: First, Write a code to create the unique number array. And second, write a code for the frequency of each number. Sample code corresponding to my thought process:

```
input_array = [3, 6, 8, 2, 4, 8, 3, 1, 8, 9, 7, 0, 5, 5, 1]
#expected_output = {'0': 1, '1': 2, '3': 2, etc.}

unique_numbers = []
frequency_array = []

#Write a code to create the unique number array
#Write a code for the frequency of each number

for inp in input_array:
    if inp not in unique_numbers:
        unique_numbers.append(inp) #Appends unique numbers to unique number array

#I thought that the following code would be able to iterate through the input array for each number in the unique number list
for un in unique_numbers:
    i = 0
    for inp in input_array:
        counter = input_array.count(unique_numbers[i]) #Count frequency
        frequency_array.append(counter) #Add count to frequency array
        counter = 0 #Return counter to 0
        i += 1 #Change i value to i+1

print('{}:{}'.format(unique_numbers, frequency_array))
```

But I get the error "list index out of range". I looked it up and it seems to have something to do with the lengths of the list "input_array" and "unique_numbers" not being the same, therefore I can't use for loop one on top of the other?

Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong? I am just beginning to learn and use python. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: By construction your `unique_numbers` list will be shorter than your `input_array`. So you will reach a point where `unique_numbers[i]` raises an index error. Why aren't you using your loop variable `un` which is looping through `unique_numbers`?

Comment: You could simply use the Counter class from Collections module......

Answer (score 0):

Just use counter under collections module:

```
import collections
l = [3, 6, 8, 2, 4, 8, 3, 1, 8, 9, 7, 0, 5, 5, 1]
c = collections.Counter(l)
print(dict(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use a library why not just:

```
dict = {}
for i in input_array:
    if i in dict.keys():
        dict[i] += 1
    else:
        dict[i] = 1
```

Comment: In this case, you can use `from collections import defaultdict` and `dict =defaultdict(0)` the code that you wrote will get an error

Comment: If your going to the effort to use collections then just use Counter from it

Comment: why would it get an error, I even tested it even though it's just a few lines

Comment: I dont see how this would give an error either, however my comment would be never call your dictonary dict, since that will overwrite the python keyword of dict function

Comment: Is there a way to do so without using dictionaries too? From the start I knew dictionaries were an obvious solution, plus several other more efficient solutions. But just for the sake of it, I was wondering how to do it by using only a counting variable and appending an empty list.

Comment: than what is the output you are looking for if not in a dictionary?